# Make complete sidebar sticky?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the complete sidebar sticky. I don't think it's possible with only css because there are two elements with dynamic height:

```
.sidebar.sidebar-main {
position: sticky;
top: 0;
}
.sidebar.sidebar-additional {
position: sticky;
top: ???;
}
```

This will not work.

I was also looking into [Magento sticky widget](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_sticky.html)
However, this does not work at all:

```
define([
"jquery",
"mage/sticky",
], function ($) {
'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.sidebar.sidebar-main').sticky({
            container: '.columns',
            spacingTop: 100,
            stickyClass: '[sticky-class]'
        });
    });
});
```

Any solution to make the complete sidebar sticky?

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap both of those elements in a new div which you can make sticky, like so:

[image]

[image]

You're correct it can't be done with only CSS as the height of the filters is dynamic, you need XML changes to achieve this.

Your XML wil be something like this, I haven't tested it:

```
<referenceContainer name="columns">
        <container name="div.sidebar.wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="sidebar-wrapper" label="Sidebar Wrapper" before="*" />
    </referenceContainer>

    <move element="div.sidebar.main" destination="div.sidebar.wrapper" />
    <move element="div.sidebar.additional" destination="div.sidebar.wrapper" />
```

Comment: Are these two blocks which I could move into a new container (which would still be child of the left column)? Then I could make this new container sticky.

Comment: Yeah, look at `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/page_layout/2columns-left.xml`. I have updated my answer with some XML that may help. It will create a wrapper, and move the sidebar elements inside it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was working on this the whole day. Unfortunately it's not that easy as it seems. Moving these blocks messes up the mobile view, which needs a lot of work to get right.